# Keras: Masking and Flattening

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm having difficulty building a straightforward model that deals with masked input values. My training data consists of variable-length lists of GPS traces, i.e. lists where each element contains Latitude and Longitude.

There are 70 training examples

[image]

Since they have variable lengths I am padding them with zeros, with the aim of then telling Keras to ignore these zero-values.

```
train_data = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(train_data, maxlen=max_sequence_len, dtype='float32', 
                                           padding='pre', truncating='pre', value=0)
```

[image]

I then build a very basic model like so

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu',input_shape=(max_sequence_len, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
```

After some previous trial and error I realised that I need the `Flatten` layer or fitting the model would throw the error

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_87 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (70, 2)
```

By including this `Flatten` layer, however, I can not use a `Masking` layer (to ignore the padded zeros) or Keras throws this error

```
TypeError: Layer flatten_31 does not support masking, but was passed an input_mask: Tensor("masking_9/Any_1:0", shape=(?, 48278), dtype=bool)
```

I have searched extensively, reading GitHub issues and plenty of Q/A here but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Masking does seem bugged. But do not worry: the 0s are not going to make your model worse; at most less efficient.

I would recommend using a Convolutional approach instead of pure Dense or perhaps RNN. I think this will work really well for GPS data.

Please try the following code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Masking, LSTM, GRU, Conv1D, Dropout, MaxPooling1D
import numpy as np
import random

max_sequence_len = 70

n_samples = 100
num_coordinates = 2 # lat/long

data = [[[random.random() for _ in range(num_coordinates)]
         for y in range(min(x, max_sequence_len))]
        for x in range(n_samples)]

train_y = np.random.random((n_samples, 2))

train_data = pad_sequences(data, maxlen=max_sequence_len, dtype='float32',
                           padding='pre', truncating='pre', value=0)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, (5, ), input_shape=(max_sequence_len, num_coordinates)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='relu'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer="adam")
model.fit(train_data, train_y)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Unfortunately it doesn't boost my accuracy, but this could well be a fault in my data. I noticed a huge discrepancy in my `max_sequence_len` (198720) and `min_sequence_len` (3!!) so this is clearly a problem

Comment: @PhilipO'Brien No worries, and understandable! I would propose to just take the first few and last, say, 200 parts of the sequences then. Also include a number for the length of the sequence. That should help!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `Flatten` layer, you could use a **Global Pooling** layer.

These are suited to collapse the length/time dimension without losing the capability of using variable lengths.

So, instead of `Flatten()`, you can try a `GlobalAveragePooling1D` or `GlobalMaxPooling1D`.

None of them use `supports_masking` in their code, so they must be used with care.

The average one will consider more inputs than the max (thus the values that should be masked).

The max will take only one from the length. With luck, if all your useful values are higher than the ones in the masked position, it will indirectly preserve the mask. It will probably need even more input neurons than the other.

That said, yes, try the `Conv1D` or RNN (`LSTM`) appoaches suggested.

---

### Creating a custom pooling layer with mask

You can also create your own pooling layer (needs a functional API model where you pass both the model's inputs and the tensor which you want to pool)

Below, a working example with average pooling applying a mask based on the inputs:

```
def customPooling(maskVal):
    def innerFunc(x):
        inputs = x[0]
        target = x[1]

        #getting the mask by observing the model's inputs
        mask = K.equal(inputs, maskVal)
        mask = K.all(mask, axis=-1, keepdims=True)

        #inverting the mask for getting the valid steps for each sample
        mask = 1 - K.cast(mask, K.floatx())

        #summing the valid steps for each sample
        stepsPerSample = K.sum(mask, axis=1, keepdims=False)

        #applying the mask to the target (to make sure you are summing zeros below)
        target = target * mask

        #calculating the mean of the steps (using our sum of valid steps as averager)
        means = K.sum(target, axis=1, keepdims=False) / stepsPerSample

        return means

    return innerFunc


x = np.ones((2,5,3))
x[0,3:] = 0.
x[1,1:] = 0.


print(x)

inputs = Input((5,3))
out = Lambda(lambda x: x*4)(inputs)
out = Lambda(customPooling(0))([inputs,out])

model = Model(inputs,out)
model.predict(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the really useful explanation. It was really difficult to decide which answer to award the bounty, but I felt that PascalVKooten's just shaded it in terms of direct applicability to my problem.